# Duplicated values as an output of python function

Tags: python, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like create a Python function for multiple SQL inserts. This function I will use in my Airflow DAG for inserts into Snowflake db. I will need do create an SnowflakeOperator which will use this function. I'm just start to use Airflow so please correct me if I'm wrong.

My example:
I'm connecting to Snowflake db in order to get data from table with information schema name and table name. This output I'm using for inserts per schema. I'm selecting schema and creating variable my_schema = 'my_schema'.

First approach:

```
sql = "SELECT SCHEMA, TABLE FROM TABLE"
cur.execute(sql)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(iter(cur), columns=[x[0] for x in cur.description])
my_dict = dict()

for i in df['SCHEMA'].unique().tolist():

    df_x = df[df['SCHEMA'] == i]
    my_dict[i] = df_x['TABLE'].tolist()

    for schema, tables in my_dict.items():
        for table in tables:
            query = f"INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} where col2 = 1;"
            try:
                cur.execute(query)
            except snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as e:
                # Something went wrong with the insert
                logging.error(f"Inserting in {schema}.{table}: {e}")

    conn.close()
```

For testing I created pandas datframe with two columns schema and table.

```
data = [['test', 'table01'], ['test', 'table02'], ['my_schema', 'table03'], ['schemaxxx', 'table04']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['schema', 'table'])
```

I created function for inserts.

```
my_schema = 'my_schema'

def my_insert_fnc(df):
    
    my_dict = dict()

    for i in df['schema'].unique().tolist():
        
        

        df_x = df[df['schema'] == i]

        my_dict[i] = df_x['table'].tolist()

        sql_list = []

        for schema, tables in my_dict.items():
            for table in tables:
                if schema == my_schema:
                    
                

                    sql_list.append(f"INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} where col2 = 1;")
                    print(sql_list)
```

But I'm getting duplicates.

```
my_insert_fnc(df_new) 

['INSERT INTO my_schema.table03 SELECT * FROM my_schema.table03 where col2 = 1;']
['INSERT INTO my_schema.table03 SELECT * FROM my_schema.table03 where col2 = 1;']
```

I would like to remove duplicates and logging errors.

```
try:
                cur.execute(query)
            except snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as e:
                # Something went wrong with the insert
                logging.error(f"Inserting in {schema}.{table}: {e}")
```

This function as I mentioned I need to use in my Airflow DAG so It needs to give me a string output in order to use it in SnowflakeOperator. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Someone who can help?

Comment: I’m trying to understand your code and I saw this: ‘df_x = df[df['schema'] == i]’. What exactly does this do? It seems to me like you are trying to index a dictionary with a Boolean value. I’m not sure if this was intentional and I don’t quite see the point in it?

Comment: @CmdCoder858 I'm creating a dictionary, key is schema with list of all tables. So dictionary with schema as a key and list of all tables.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 any advice?

Comment: @My80 are you trying to use Snowflake connector For Python in your Python code , then can you not use write_pandas dataframe function to write df to table https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#write_pandas

Comment: I think this issue is probably arising from this line: ‘df_x = df[df['schema'] == i]’. Here you are indexing the data frame based on a Boolean value, which means you can only ever access the first 2 values. I have no idea why you would do it this way as it just seems to be completely pointless at best, could you perhaps try a method that doesn’t use this syntax? I can’t test anything right now but I could test some things out tonight if you can’t get it to work.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 this is solution from stackoverflow and it works. I created dictionary with schema name as a key and list of tables. I have a issue with duplicates from my function.

Comment: @akshindesnowflake I'm trying to create multiple inserts statements which I will use in Airflow dag in my SnowflakeOperator. So dataframe is not what I need.

Comment: Assuming most of your code is correct, which seems to be the case but I can't be certain of, it seems like you are still construction the dictionary while you are operating on it. The second for loop must be underneath the first one, not inside it because you are looping through a dictionary that contains the schema you want twice, and more times if you added more to your test data. Unindent the second for loop outside the first one and you should no longer have problems with duplicate output.